# How to Aggregate Weighted averages fields at different levels of granularity?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am calculating weighted formula for a field as sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) and this is as per the below query. Now I will be creating a view that would store these results as I shown in code below.

My question is, if I select this w_revenue out of the view and want to see per year, how will I aggregate to show it per year? See desired outputs.

```
select month,item, sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) as w_revenue,
year
from my_revenue_table
group by month, year,item;

create view xyz as 
    select month,item, sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) as w_revenue,
    year
    from my_revenue_table
    group by month, year,item;

select w_revenue 
from xyz.
```

How do I do this so as to aggregate this per year?

```
Year    Month   Item    Revenue Qty Sum(revenue)/Sum(Qty)
2019    Mar      A       10      2    5
2019    Mar      B       30      3    10
2019    Feb      C       50      1    50
2019    Feb      D       20      2    10
```

Expected value if I see per year:

```
Year    Sum(revenue)/Sum(Qty)
2019    13.75                         (10+30+50+20)/(2+3+1+2)
```

Comment: btw what DBMS are you using mySQL or Oracle ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I am using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

group on by `year` then create another view as

```
create view abc as
select sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) as w_revenue, year
  from my_revenue_table
 group by year;
```

and call

```
select * from xyz union all
select null, null, a.* from abc a
```

to combine them, if I understood you correctly.

or revenue per year repeating at every row as

```
select x.*,
       (select w_revenue
         from abc
        where year = x.year) as w_revenue_year      
  from xyz x
```

Comment: I have to select from view and not from the query. How do I aggregate in view?

Comment: @Yogesh please elaborate the display style what you want to see the results

Comment: I want to display the data per year but my view is at lower level as it is till item or month level. I have given example in my question as to what I am expecting and what my query or view data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do the aggregation you want from the view.  You don't have enough information.

If you change the view to something like this:

```
create view xyz as 
    select year, month, item,
           sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) as w_revenue,
           sum(qty) as total_qty
    from my_revenue_table
    group by month, year, item;
```

Then you can aggregate the results as:

```
select year, sum(w_revenue * total_qty) / sum(total_qty)
from xyz
group by year;
```

EDIT:

Or just modify the view to have the information you want:

```
create view xyz as 
    select year, month, item,
           sum(revenue)/ Sum(qty) as w_revenue,
           sum(qty) as total_qty,
           (sum(sum(revenue)) over (partition by year, item) / 
            sum(sum(qty)) over (partition by year, item)
           ) as w_revenue_year
    from my_revenue_table
    group by month, year, item;
```

Comment: I actually want to have this field available to user without his intervention in it. I am using Oracle BI tool to expose this field for reporting purpose. I cannot ask user to do sum(w_revenue * total_qty) / sum(total_qty) in report itself to get the results, that's the reason I wanted to add this to view itself. Please suggest.